# text substation in zsh/oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

having a strange problem since starting to use zsh,  which is not present in bash.  I am using both zsh and oh-my-zsh,  I think I have narrowed the problem to oh-my-zsh

My old password has a !2 in it.  When I type !2 the text gets replaced to cd ->dev

```
[jellin:~]$ !2
[jellin:~]$ cd dev
```

haven't a clue whats doing this.  Any ideas? Seems like an odd substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply history id expansion. To prove this,

```
$ history | grep 'cd dev' | head
```

You will see that around id 2, you did a `cd dev`.

Comment: Yes, exactly correct,  however you were too quick for me to accept the answer.  Says I can do it in 8mins.